# What is the meaning of Confucius' 一以貫之

Tags: traditional-characters

What is the meaning of Confucius' 一以貫之 yī yǐ guàn zhī 
Literary Chinese :孔子 禮記 論語 請問何謂孔子吾道一以貫之？曾子曰：唯；夫子之道忠恕而已矣。

Comment: bkrs：一以贯之。用一个根本性的事理贯通事情的始末或全部的道理。 One principle runs through it all.; one unity pervading all things.For more info search web using 一以贯之

Answer (score 1):

The expression can be a verb, meaning using a principle to handle all kinds of affairs.